# Angular js ng-disabled doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my form

```
<form name="myForm">
<input ng-disabled="true" type="text" >*
</form>
```

However I am trying to understand why this input field is not disabled?

I also tried with a $scope, so in the CTRL:

```
$scope.diss=true;
```

and in html :

```
<form name="myForm">
<input ng-disabled="diss" type="text" >*
</form>
```

It still doesnt work, any hint?

Comment: Did you forget to use `ng-app` on some element wrapping your form?

Comment: why don't you try disabled="true" in that input...?

Comment: Can you pust plunker/jsfiddle snippet that shows this issue? This plunker with copy-paste of your code shows that it is valid code: http://plnkr.co/edit/yKdRvSCwGDC8p62vx21v?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple working example of the `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<form ng-app> 
   <input ng-disabled="checked" type="text" />
    Click me to disable: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: see above with ng-app included

Answer (score 1):

I could not use ng-disabled with angular prior to version 1.2.x (I am on 1.0.8) because my jQuery version was 1.4.2.

angularJS 1.0.x requires jQuery 1.6 or newer.

Upgrading either your jQuery or angularJS will fix the issue - angularJS 1.2.x detects your jQuery version and will fallback to its internal jQLite.